# How to get en post nested object in asp.net webapi?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

A newbie question.
Just started on asp.net web api project that going well getting and posting plain object.

But how doe I Get and Post object with child objects. The same as Order with order items.

Who cab help me with a simple example without advance features as OData etc.

Thanks in advance

Anders Pedersen

Answer (score 0):

Create your object graph and return it so that web API can serialize it for you. So, you will create an `Order` object like this and return it.

```
public Order Get(int id)
{
    var order = new Order() { Id = id };
    order.OrderItems.Add(new OrderItem() { ProductName = "Cool Item", Price = 12.34 };
    order.OrderItems.Add(new OrderItem() { ProductName = "Cool Item", Price = 12.34 };

    return order;
}
```

If you now look at the JSON or XML payload of this GET response, that is what you will need to post to get the binding work with your POST action method.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Order order) { ... }
```